# Facebook login in android WebView

Tags: android, html, facebook, cordova

I'm developing an android app with phonegap and html5. Can anyone tell me how to implement Facebook login button. Also I need to know, how to implement share on wall functionality. I tried using facebook phonegap plugin, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the "Hackbook" example provided with the SDK sources.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/Hackbook/src/com/facebook/android/LoginButton.java